Reference request for the existence of minimal sufficient statistics
I'd like a recent paper or book that shows in what conditions we can guarantee the existence of a minimal sufficient statistic.
I know the paper "Sufficiency and Statistical Decision Functions" (by R.R. Bahadur) and "Completeness, Similar Regions, and Unbiased Estimation: Part I" (by  Lehmann and Scheffé). But these papers use weird notations and, therefore, are hard to understand. So I'd like a more recent paper or book about the existence of minimal sufficient statistics.
Thank you for your attention!

I know that there're statistical models that doesn't have minimal sufficient statistics, as you can see in the paper "Minimal Sufficient $\sigma$-Fields and Minimal Sufficient Statistics. Two Counterexamples".
What I want to know is some conditions that guarantee the existence of minimal sufficient statistics.

As a useful start, Theorem 34.7 in Probability and Measure (3rd ed.) by Patrick Billingsley (it is not a recent book, though) states a sufficient condition for a minimal sub-$\sigma$-field to exist (which encompasses sufficient statistics as a special case).
